# ASP.NET Core MVC loading an xml to a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am fairly new to C# and ASP.NET Core MVC.

I am trying to load an XML onto a dropdown here is what i managed to build.
Was trying to find ways in loading an xml and also the proper way of doing it and loading onto the dropdown.

The view model with `IEnumerable` is from my Entity Framework data.

View:

```
<div class="form-group flex-row marginForInputBoxes">
        <label for="Vendor" class="labelmargin">Vendor:</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor("i dont know what to put")
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        NBFETableListViewModel nbfeListViewModel = new NBFETableListViewModel();
        nbfeListViewModel.TableData = _loggerRepository.AllData;
        return View(nbfeListViewModel);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class NBFETableListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<TestIgnore> TableData { get; set; }

   
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Processes>
<Process>
    <id>1</id>
    <ConfigFile>Process1.xml</ConfigFile>
</Process>
<Process>
    <id>2</id>
    <ConfigFile>SecondProcess.xml</ConfigFile>
</Process>
<Process>
    <id>3</id>
    <ConfigFile>Process3.xml</ConfigFile>
</Process>
</Processes>
```

Comment: The best method for parsing an xml file depend on a lot of factors.  1) The size of the XML 2) The amount of data you need to extract 3) The structure of the xml

Comment: Just try to serialize your XML to List. Then add that list to your view model, and make an "for" loop with options inside of select. Or you can use ViewBag. It depend how big is your data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the half-baked answer, but i can't add a comment.

You should de-serialize that XML into something more usable like an list or an custom object, from there adding it to a dropdown would be easier

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-5.0